# PHP CURL rarely SSL connect error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, nginx

We have an instance of a nginx web server, that some of our applications use. And last time we started getting `cURL error #35 - SSL connect error`. But we don't get it continuously just about 2-3 times per 100 requests. Requests go from different sources (C# app, Unix-app, some php scripts etc.) And I'm confused because we can't find a reason of this problem.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`  makes a falirue at all.

What could it be?

Comment: @PaulCrovella If I miss some details you can just tell and I will update the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) website, it states:

> **CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35)**
>
> A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. You really want
>   the error buffer and read the message there as it pinpoints the
>   problem slightly more. Could be certificates (file formats, paths,
>   permissions), passwords, and others

Certainly with the PHP scripts it should be possible to edit them so that there is some extra debug information available to help debug ( could write to a text file etc ) - if the error persists and there is no info in the debug info then at least you have eliminated one source. I don't know how you would do the same for the unix app or the c# app - there most likely would be a way.